# Semantic-ui : Stop url change when a tab is clicked

Tags: javascript, html, tabs, semantic-ui

I'm trying to use [Semantic-ui Tab](https://semantic-ui.com/modules/tab.html) module. And it's working.

**HTML Code:**

```
<div class="ui large modal" id="some-modal">
    <div class="ui top attached tabular menu">
        <div class="item" data-tab="first">first</div>
        <div class="item" data-tab="second">second</div>
        <div class="item" data-tab="third">third</div>
    </div>
    <div class="ui bottom attached tab segment" data-tab="first">
        first tab content
    </div>
    <div class="ui bottom attached tab segment" data-tab="second">
        second tab content
    </div>
    <div class="ui bottom attached tab segment" data-tab="third">
        third tab content
    </div>
</div>
```

**Javascript Code :**

```
$('.menu .item').tab();
```

**What is creating trouble :**

When any tab is clicked the default functionality is that it changes the url of the page to the `data-tab` attribute's value. For eg. when somebody clicks on the tab-1, the url is changed to `http://localhost#/first` (as the data-tab attribute value for tab-1 is "first").

Is there some way by which we can stop this from happening. This change of url is disturbing my other functionalities. Otherwise I need to make too many changes in my application to make it work.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [document](https://semantic-ui.com/modules/tab.html#/settings)

Just simply set history to false

```
$('.menu .item').tab({history: false});
```

Comment: Thanks... :) mistakenly missed that part of the documentation.